# Reuse Xamarin Forms page in Xamarin.IOS Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

My aim is to be able to reuse **Xamarin Forms pages** in my **xamarin.ios** project. I know that it is possible for ios extensions. However, can it be achieved in an **xamarin.ios** application project?

Comment: Did you want to open a forms page in iOS project ?

Comment: yes i want to open a forms page in iOS project